# JavaScript: Include/Append objects/buttons inside a <span>

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a really long javascript code which basically has a form and generates buttons.

I want to place the buttons together inside a  tag so i could fix up their appearance as a group.

How do I achieve this?

i know i basically have to use "document.createElement ("span")" but i'm kind of stuck there... please help

Comment: you can use css for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use JQuery? it has .wrap() method, or when you generates form and buttons, directly wrap the buttons in a 'span', good luck!